# Gas out of lung while doing russian twists

Tags: exercise, breathing

when I'm doing russian twist I can feel air went out of my mouth with slight wheezing sound. I mean the physics is obvious (ofc gas go out when I do exercise that put pressure on lung) but I just want to make 3x sure that this is okay/normal esp with the wheezing sound? It's not my lung get punctured slightly? Currently I'm not doing this, and as I breath normally and I don't feel anything different except maybe 5% more difficult to breathe (like when you're underwater, but not that much) and after 10 minutes it's gone (still feel this air going out when I twist).

The reason I'm worried about punctured lung (or any kind of possible weird but potentially fatal trauma) is because I fell during ski and instead of bruising muscle pain, I feel weird ticklish-every 15second kind of sharp pain deep inside near the liver/under ribcage area. I really don't think it's punctured lung because it should produce more noticeable symptom (like collapsed lung) and should not cause air to go out... but I'm triple checking because I'm not an expert on this kind of thing.

If this help: I skied once in my life and I was on green slope so it was fine except I didn't know how to stop/turn, I go straight full speed from top to bottom and fell on my left side at the bottom with pretty high speed (for me) and went unconscious for 1 minute. Then this sharp pain happened on my center-right side, but it wasn't bad so I ignored it.

I'm 25y/o female, physically at the normal weight (120lbs/5'4") but I've never exercised until 2-3 weeks ago (the "go upstairs 2 floors and out of breath"- kind of person). I have a slight asthma when I was young but never bothered me much. Recently I started to do more cardio-type exercises (bike/run) and like a normal unfit person I ran out of breath very easily etc. This has happened for 2-3 weeks and I'm better at endurance. This wheezing thing never happened ever, even when I ran out of breath with other cardio type exercises. Only noticed after I started to do this russian twist.

Thanks people!

Comment: Sounds completely normal. Try standing up, and simply twisting your upper body. It's normal to have a compression exhalation. And no, a collapsed or punctured lung is absolutely out of the question. You wouldn't be typing if that were the case.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot! I can do these new exercises without worries :)

Comment: Me too! And a recent Cardiogram showed slight enlargment of my heart! What is going on!!! Its not normal because I do Yoga and have been for years and have never heard this until after heart problems started!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not worry about your lungs, they are completely normal. Punctured lungs is a very different clinical condition that needs to be operated. Clue: When you do the twist do not let the motion make the air out of your lungs, you need to contract the side you twisted toward and you squeeze the air out in your control. You will get more benefit by doing this.